# How do i store the names in the list so that when i enter a new name the old ones that i have entered stay?

Tags: python-3.5

```
while True:
    goodList = ["Max","James"]
    badList = ["Bradley"]

    childName = input("What name is it?")
    childBehaviour = input("Have they been bad or good?")
    answer = (childName)
    if childBehaviour == 'good':
        goodList.append(answer)
        print('GoodList' + str(goodList))
    if childBehaviour == 'bad':
        badList.append(answer)
        print('BadList' + str(badList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing the two lists `goodList` and `badList` at each step of the while loop. 
To avoid that, initialize them outside (before) the while loop:

```
goodList = ["Max","James"]
badList = ["Bradley"]

while True:
    childName = input("What name is it?")
    childBehaviour = input("Have they been bad or good?")
    answer = (childName)
    if childBehaviour == 'good':
        goodList.append(answer)
        print('GoodList' + str(goodList))
    if childBehaviour == 'bad':
        badList.append(answer)
        print('BadList' + str(badList))
```